# CS0120 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Robot.PrintValues()" требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#, .net, классы, методы

начал обучаться языку, и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Повторяю код полностью за человеком на видео, но при этом возникает ошибка: CS0120 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Robot.PrintValues()" требуется ссылка на объект.

Стоит поставить параметр static, все пропадает, но так как я изучаю виртуальный метод, это решение не представляется возможным. При этом у "преподавателя" работает все, а у меня ничего.

Пытался искать ошибку в Metanit.net, там я не нашел (или не понял). Искал ошибку в Microsoft: Решения, которые он мне предлагает не помогают. Плюс в силу неопытности, я просто не понимаю, что от меня требует программа: Какая ссылка? Какие аргументы?
Началось это с обучения классов, но сейчас заставила врасплох. Пожалуйста объясните

Код:

```
    '''
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Security.AccessControl;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConstructsClasses
    {
        internal class Program
        {
          public static void Main() 
            {
            Robot Boba = new Robot("Boba", 100, new byte[] { 5, 7, 10 });
        Boba.name = "Boba";
        Boba.weight = 100;
        Boba.coordinates = new byte[] { 5, 7, 10 };
        Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} \nВес: {1} \nКоординаты: ", Boba.name, Boba.weight);
        foreach (byte b in Boba.coordinates)  Console.Write("{0} ", b);

        Killer Biba = new Killer("Biba", 120, new byte[] { 10, 6, 8 }, 100);
        Biba.name = "Biba";
        Biba.weight = 120;
        Biba.coordinates = new byte[] { 10, 6, 8 };
        Biba.Health = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} \nВес: {1} \nКоординаты: ", Biba.name, Biba.weight);
        foreach (byte b in Biba.coordinates) Console.Write("{0} ", b);
        Killer.Laser();

        Robot Bot = new Robot();
        Bot.name = "Bot";
        Bot.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Bot.coordinates = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} \nВес: {1} \nКоординаты: ", Bot.name, Bot.weight);
        foreach (byte b in Bot.coordinates) Console.Write("{0} ", b);
        //Массив объектов (Классов)
        List<Killer> robots = new List<Killer>();
        robots.Add(new Killer("Alex", 400, new byte[] { 10, 0, 0 }, 100));
        robots.Add(new Killer("Bob", 200, new byte[] { 0, 10, 0 }, 100));
        robots.Add(new Killer("Kenny", 600, new byte[] { 0, 0, 10 }, 100));
        robots.Add(new Killer("Cartman", 1000, new byte[] { 0, 20, 0 }, 100));
        Robot newRobot = new Robot();
        foreach (Killer obj in robots) 
        { if (obj.Name == "Kenny") 
            { newRobot = obj as Robot; } 
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
            Robot.PrintValues();  //<--- Ошибка CS0120!!!
        }
    }
    
}
//Классы
internal class Robot
{
    public string? name;
    public int weight;
    public byte[]? coordinates;
    protected string? surname;
    public int Weight 
    {   get {return this.weight;} 
        set { if (value < 1) this.weight = 1; else this.weight = value; }
    
    
    }
     public int Width{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get { return this.name; } private set { } }



    public Robot(string? name, int weight, byte[] coordinates) 
    { Console.WriteLine("Object has been created!"); 
    SetValues(name, weight, coordinates);
    
    
    }

    public Robot()
    {
    }

    public void SetValues(string? name, int weight, byte[] coordinates)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;

    }
    public static void Print () { Console.WriteLine("Buba"); }

    public virtual void PrintValues() { 
    Console.WriteLine("Bimba");} //<--- Виртуальный метод

}
//Дочерний класс
class Killer : Robot 
{ public int Health { get; set;} 
public static void Laser() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Laser shooting!!!!");
    }
    public Killer(string? name, int weight, byte[] coordinates, int health) : base (name, weight, coordinates)
    {
        this.Health = health;
        Robot.Print();
        this.surname = name;
    }

    public override void PrintValues()
    {
           base.PrintValues();
           Console.WriteLine("Health: " + this.Health);
     }
   }
 }

'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод Robot.PrintValues(); как статический, коем он не является.
Попробуйте вызывать через экземпляр.

Comment: Про экземпляры на курсе не было ни слова. Можете уточнить название темы, чтобы я мог изучить и попробовать?

Comment: Экземпляр, это тот же объект (грубо говоря), который вы создаёте вот так:  Robot robot = new Robot();
Вызывайте метод PrintValues() не как статический, через класс Robot , а как на уровне экземпляра: robot.PrintValues();

Comment: Помогло. Как я понял, при создании экземпляра программа требует его название, а не название класса. Спасибо